# System.NullReferenceException in Linq2Db "BeginTransactionAsync"

Tags: c#, linq2db

I'm coming across a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference is not set to an instance of an object` when trying to create a `DataConnectionTransaction` via LinqToDb. The top two items within the parsed call stack are as follows:

```
      {
        "assembly": "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "method": "lambda_method",
        "level": 0,
        "line": 0
      },
      {
        "assembly": "linq2db, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e41013125f9e410a",
        "method": "LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection+<BeginTransactionAsync>d__0.MoveNext",
        "level": 1,
        "line": 0
      },
```

It seems as though the error stems from a call to `BeginTransactionAsync`, and is encountered in a lambda method. I am a bit lost as to where this lambda method is coming from, even after observing the Linq2Db source code here: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Source/LinqToDB/Data/DataConnection.Async.cs.

If anyone has encountered something similar, I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: If you want help debugging the open source project, or your own code that calls the open source project, see duplicate. If you want the owner of the open source project to assist with debugging, you should probably contact them directly.

Comment: Add more details and open issue in github.